# I need DateTime in SELECT, but if in GROUP BY provides unusable report

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

My boss needs a report that has 3 columns sorted by date and time. One column is information from the current month. The second column is information from last month. The last column is information from the year to date. The rest of the columns in the report are static information that won't change. Right now I can get the report to work perfect for just the current month.

---

My issue is that to get the extra columns, it is breaking another part of the report.

I need to be able to keep all sales with the same item number to just be added together into the same row, and the only relevant information that it needs to pull from each additional sale of the item is is the quantity that was sold (invoice_itemized.Quantity).

Example of Code without: `invoice_totals.DateTime`

https://ideone.com/3esPpQ

Example of Code with: `Invoice_totals.dateTime`

https://ideone.com/K1gFBi

**What it's doing:**

- With invoice_Totals.DateTime in GROUP BY, every single invoice (with different dates and times) are going into their own rows.

**What it needs to do:**

- All invoices with the same ItemNumber (Inventory.ItemNum) need to be grouped together in the same row.
- A column with Month to date, last month and year to date.

Comment: FIRST REPORT [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeaBQ.png
SECOND REPORT  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYh2I.png

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Different products, and different answers.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: Thank you, I will make the update. I am using MS SQL Server.

Comment: If you make some effort simplifying your problem, you will get better answers - faster! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get three different totals:

- month to date
- total for last month
- year to date

I would argue that its pretty difficult to get that with one query.

If I was doing this, I'd probably do it as a stored procedure that prepared the different totals in temporary tables and then joined it altogether at the end. So something like:

```
-- get the month to date 
SELECT 
(Inventory.ItemNum) AS [Item Number], 
cast(SUM(Invoice_Itemized.Quantity) as decimal(19,2)) AS [Month to Date], 
INTO #tmpMonthToDate
FROM blah blah .... blah
GROUP BY (Inventory.ItemNum)

-- then get last month into temp table
SELECT 
(Inventory.ItemNum) AS [Item Number], 
cast(SUM(Invoice_Itemized.Quantity) as decimal(19,2)) AS [Last Month], 
INTO #tmpLastMonth
FROM blah blah .... blah
GROUP BY (Inventory.ItemNum)

-- then get year to date
SELECT 
(Inventory.ItemNum) AS [Item Number], 
cast(SUM(Invoice_Itemized.Quantity) as decimal(19,2)) AS [Year To Date], 
INTO #tmpYearToDate
FROM blah blah .... blah
GROUP BY (Inventory.ItemNum)

-- then join the three totals with all the other stuff
SELECT DISTINCT
(Inventory.ItemNum) AS [Item Number], 
(Departments.Dept_ID) AS [Brand], 
(Inventory.ItemName) AS [Description], 
(Inventory.ItemName_Extra) AS [Size], 
(cast(Inventory.Cost as decimal(19,2))) AS [Unit Cost], 
(cast(Inventory.Price as decimal(19,2))) AS [Unit Price], 
(cast(IIF(Inventory.Cost > '0' AND Inventory.Price > '0', Inventory.Cost / Inventory.Price * 100, '0') as decimal(19,2))) AS [GM%], 
(cast(Inventory.In_Stock as decimal(19,0))) AS [QOH-Units],
tm.[Month to Date],
tl.[Last Month],
ty.[Year To Date]
FROM blah blah ... blah
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpMonthToDate tm 
     on tm.[Item Number] = Inventory.ItemNum
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpLastMonth tl 
     on tl.[Item Number] = Inventory.ItemNum  
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpYearToDate ty 
     on ty.[Item Number] = Inventory.ItemNum
```

... I've left out quite a lot there but I hope its enough to show the idea.

Where is the final output going - to SSRS?

Comment: Thank you for this response. I hadn't thought to try this. I have got it partially working now and I am trying to work out the kinks now.

Comment: I haven't entirely worked out where the final output will be going. I was originally writing the query to be imported directly into the POS software Cash Register Express which supports custom reports imported with raw sql script. But it doesn't seem to handle the formatting well so I have been trying to find a different solution for that.